# How to exclude matplotlib figure from show() call?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-widget

I have a class that owns some matplotlib figures, axes, artists, etc.  It has functions for manipulating and displaying these that all work fine when working with instances of the class.

However, if a user wants to make some separate matplotlib plots in, say, another cell of a notebook that contains instances of my class, all the class's figures get displayed when the user calls plt.show() to display their own figures.

I'm using ipympl, `%matplotlib widget`, and setting plt.ioff().

Is there a way for me to set my figures so that they are not displayed when plt.show() is called?

Example: Consider these two Jupyter Notebook cells (have to be split for first figure to display)

```py
%matplotlib widget
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.ioff()

class interactiveplot(object):
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        plt.ioff()
        self.fig,self.ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2))
        self.plot, = self.ax.plot(x,y)
    def update(self,x,y):
        self.plot.set_data(x,y)
        self.fig.canvas.draw()
    def show(self):
        return self.fig.canvas

#create class instance
test = interactiveplot([1,2,3,4],[4,1,5,7])
#display figure
test.show()
```

```py
#Change data in displayed figure
test.update([2,3],[6,5])

#display a plot of something totally unrelated
fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(2,2))
ax.scatter([2.3,3.4],[34,23])
plt.show()
#Both test.fig and fig are displayed!  I only want to see fig!
```

Comment: If you are sure you never want to show the figure via `plt.show()` you can just close it, `plt.close(self.fig)`

Comment: I never want to display it via `plt.show()`, but I still want to be able to display it by accessing the canvas with ipympl as in the `interactiveplot.show()` function of my example class.

Comment: That's hardly possible, at least if you want to retain the interactive nature of the plot (with zooming etc.).

Comment: Yes, that is what I want. I was afraid it might not be possible. Doesn't mean it shouldn't be possible... to set some attribute of a figure that excludes it from a global call to plt.show().

Comment: Is there a way perhaps to call `show()` but to redirect the output somewhere it won't actually display?

Comment: xref: https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/issues/16377